# Defining class attributes from XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have 2 attributes which I want to add my View class as following:

```
[Att1]
[Att2]
class MyView {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to define these attributes somehow from XAML directly (for example with an markup-extension), so the Visual Studio adds them into the generated cs-file, like it defines the class name with **x:class** attribute?

e.g.

```
<Window x:Class="MyView" x:Attributes="Att1 Att2" ...
```